# Quartz Cron Job scheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a Job in the Quartz Cron job format to run everyday at 4:30am. so i did   0 30 4 */1 * ?   . Will this work good.  How different is this expression when compared to  0 30 4 * * ?  . Plz tell me, if they are going to work the same or not !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should work equally. `*/1` is cron idiom for "every 1 day", but that is already the default for cron expressions unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't the `*` in the seconds field mean 'run every seconds'?

Comment: @ABVincita Yes, you're right, I just checked. I don't know why I said that back then. Fixed.